# Registering an account using Web service on c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to register an account using web services, but it's not working. It doesn't give me an error, however the data isn't inserted into the table. I think there's is a problem in the way I am communicating with the web service.

Comment: Why are you hiding exceptions?  `catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }`   It might be valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are sending the data in query string but you are using post method to send data.
Please post the data to the URL or change your register method to read the data from query string.

You can try changing if your service is expecting data as query string

request.Method = "POST"; 
to 
request.Method = "GET";